# How do I change all CSS for a shopify buy button in an external HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

I recently started a e-commerce and made it trough shopify. Now i made a separate HTML and css for my website because I wanted to it myself. So i pasted in the shopify Buy Button thing and now I wonder how i can edit the css for the Buy button in my HTML since there is almost none to edit in the code I got from the shopify Buy Button thing?

When looking at the site in inspector on google chrome i clearly see that there is more css then in my html file so how can i edit all of the css for the buy button?

*Sorry for any grammatic faults*

The css thats imbedded in the html and script code I got from shopify Buy button does not contain all css for the Buy button. I've been digging around a bit now and can't seem to find anything that might fix this so hoping posting here will :)

Or is it possible to make a totally new style.css and customize everything from scratch? That would be perfect aswell since i know css and html i just want the buy feature.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To change the CSS for a Shopify buy button in an external HTML file, you can use the style attribute on the  element to add inline styles. For example:`<button style="background-color: red; color: white;">Buy Now</button>`

Alternatively, you can use a stylesheet to define the styles for the button and then apply those styles using the class attribute on the `<button>` element.

`<button class="buy-button">Buy Now</button>`

`.buy-button { background-color: red; color: white; }`

Comment: Thanks, but i don't see where i can get the class names in my code, codepen.io/vancee/pen/BaVvYea , could you just clarify how I change the css for specific things in there

Comment: The HTML itself should have the class names, ID names, etc. You can override all external styling with inline STYLE attributes. If there are classes in an external CSS file on the (Shopify server, say), the developer tools in a browser should let you see what is assigned to each HTML element.